# mouse click in margins to move point (gui macos) rather than error?

Tags: mouse, gui-emacs, margins

Currently, I have text modes configured with wide margins for readability with

```
(defun text-margins ()
  (setq left-margin-width 16)
  (setq right-margin-width 16))
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'text-margins)
```

in my init.

And this is great, except that sometimes I want to use the mouse to move point to the beginning of a line (in the GUI, on MacOS).

Clicking on a line inside the text moves point to the location clicked, as expected.

However, clicking on my nice wide margin next to a line doesn't move point. Instead, it beeps at me with an error and leaves point where it started.

Is there any way to catch a mouse event inside a margin, so that I can give it a function to move point rather than just yell at me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok y'all, I figured it out myself.  The following code works even on the bottom half of split windows and on inactive windows.

```
  (defun set-point-to-margin-click (event) 
    (interactive "e")
    (let ((position (cddr (mouse-position)))
         (clicked-window (posn-window (event-start event))))
      (select-window clicked-window)
      (let ((topline (car (cdr (window-body-edges)))))
        (move-to-window-line 0)
        (line-move-visual (- position topline)))))
      
    (global-set-key (kbd "<left-margin> <mouse-1>") 'set-point-to-margin-click)
    (global-set-key (kbd "<right-margin> <mouse-1>") 'set-point-to-margin-click)
```